# How to design distcp job using hue-oozie

Tags: hadoop, oozie, hue

I am trying setup distcp job in hue oozie browser.
[image]

Not sure what are the parameter to provide where?

```
hadoop distcp hdfs://nn1:8020/source/first hdfs://nn1:8020/source/second
```

Which xml should be job.xml and what are the param values??

Answer (score 0):

Hue comes with examples, did you look at the DisCp one? (in your installation or [demo.gethue.com](http://demo.gethue.com/jobsub/#edit-design/5)).

Note that the Distcp action in the new editor (Hue 3.8+) is much simpler to use.